# Retrieve data from MongoDB and save it to global object in Node.js and Express.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, javascript-objects

I'm trying to get data from MongoDB collection and then save it to a global object.Later I need to parse it to HTML template.
Here is my code:

**When user log onto his profile: then we need to get his projects and here we call findeprojects() function**

```
usrRouter.route('/profile')
    .all(function (req,res,next) {

        if(!req.user){
            res.redirect('/');
        }
        next();
    })
    .get(function (req,res,userObj) {
       // var proj = findprojects();

        userObj = req.user;
        var pro = {};
        pro = findprojects(userObj);
        res.render('index',{name:userObj.username, email:userObj.email});
        //res.sendFile('profile.html',{root:path.join(__dirname,'../public'),},{name:userObj.username});
    });
```

**Here is findeprojects function code:**

```
var findprojects = function(obj) {
var usern = obj.username;
mongodb.connect(url,function(err, db){
  if(err) throw err;

  var collection = db.collection('projects');
    //console.log(usern);
    collection.find({'pusername':usern});
    cursor =db.collection('projects').find({ 'pusername': usern }).toArray(function(err,items){
          //console.log(items);
          var i;
          for(i=0; i<items.length;){
              userProjects.createdBy = items[i].pusername;
              userProjects.proName   = items[i].projectName;
              userProjects.proType   = items[i].projectType;
              userProjects.proDesc   = items[i].projectDesc;
              //return userProjects;
            i = i+1;
          }

    });
    console.log(userProjects);
});
```

};

**I have declared global object at the top like:**

```
userProjects = {
createdBy:'',
proName:'',
proType:'',
proDesc:''
};
```

But when I console userprojects object after calling the findeprojects() function it displays empty values.

Comment: Are you getting this value after for loop?

Comment: To be brutally honest: it looks like you don't know how to work with the asynchronous nature of Node, and are trying to work around it using globals (which are not the solution to your problem). I think it would be easier if you started with something much simpler (there are a lot of moving parts in the code you're posting), and read a good tutorial on how to handle asynchronous functions.

Comment: If you want to just see your data you can move the `console.log` statement in side of the callback function in your `toArray` method. But I also agree with @rokeryklep.

Comment: can you help me please!

Comment: any resource to understand async functions?

Comment: I have tried :   var findprojects = function(obj, callback){}                                   and at the end i have return return callback(userprojects);                                    but console through error which says callback is not a function.                      I'm new to nodejs help me please!

Comment: @AbdulRehman I can't really recommend a good book or tutorial (simply because I don't know any), but I believe that [Node.js in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/node-js-in-action) is a very common book used to learn Node with.

Answer (score 2):

why dont you use mongoose to model your stuff.
its more intuitive and you no need to declare the global object and do the mapping in the for loop that you are doing.

also your approach is a bit wrong in terms of when you iterate through for aren't you overwriting ?
say you have two documents where pusername is abdul.
so in your case you loose first object which will get overwritten by the second one.

i see that you commented out a return statement but even that wont work properly.

from a design point of view your approach is not efficient.

in mongoose you can do:

```
    {

    var userProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      createdBy: { type: String }
    , proName: String
    , proType: String
    , proDesc: String
    });


// Find a single document by username.
userProjectSchema.findOne({ pusername : 'abdul' }, function(err, resDoc) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  // do your html stuff here
});

// Find all documents.
userProjectSchema.find(function(err, results) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  // do your html stuff here
});


    }
```